# Doctrine 2. How to force entity from proxy

Tags: proxy, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading

I have 3 entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="table_a")
 */

class A
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */
   protected $id;

   /**
    * ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="entityA")
    */
   protected $entitiesB;

   /**
    * ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="C", mappedBy="entityA")
    */
   protected $entitiesC;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
   protected $name;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="table_b")
 */

class B
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */
   protected $id;

   /**
    * ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="entitiesB")
    */
   protected $entityA;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="date")
    */
   protected $date;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="table_c")
 */

class C
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */
   protected $id;

   /**
    * ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="entitiesC")
    */
   protected $entityA;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
   protected $description;
}
```

And I have the following situation:

```
$eB = $repositoryB->find(1);
$eA = $eB->getEntityA(); // $eA will be a proxy
$eC = new C();
$eC->setDescription('XXXXXXXXXX')
   ->setEntityA($eA);
```

This will generate an error because $eA is a proxy not an entity. Even if I try:

```
$eB = $repositoryB->find(1);
$eA = $repositoryA->find(1);
$eC = new C();
$eC->setDescription('XXXXXXXXXX')
   ->setEntityA($eA);
```

Will still get an error because once you have fetched a B entity it will automatically fetch a proxy of A entity. And when you try to fetch the A entity with the same identifier as the proxy Doctrine will return the proxy object from the Identity Map because you can not have two objects (one proxy and one Entity) for the same db record.

So is there a way to force retrieving an entity from its proxy? Or another way to set an association, by id not by entity?

Comment: The code which you wrote should work, please post the relevant errors that you are talking about.

Comment: I did'nt post the error because it will be confusing and irelevant to the problem. Here is the error: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException' with message 'A new entity was found through the relationship 'A#entitiesB' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: . To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).' in \library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 336"

Comment: The problem is that $eA is a proxy not an entity. If i do $eA = $repositoryA->find(xx), where xx is a different identifier than the one in the proxy class it will be an entity and the code will work. The problem is that i can not have 2 object for the same record. I have also tried getting $eB by query builder like "SELECT b, a FROM B b JOIN b.entityA a WHERE b.id = 1" but it still gives me a proxy

Comment: Looks like in that error EntitiesB is attached to EntityA. But in your example EntityA is attached to some other Entity (the other way around). Do you have custom getters and setters? And how does your persist() and flush() look like?

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the replies. I have found the problem. After reading http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies I realize that the problem had to be somewhere else. So I start reviewing my code again and found the inside my entity C class, inside the setEntityA function there was a variable misspelled. Because of that doctrine throw-ed an error which made my ZF skip the code from my action, and because in the postDispach function I had the flush function that is why I got that error message.

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to remove the question or maybe the title should be changed so that other users don't have to waste time reading this as the problem came down to a spelling error.